# NSHomeDirectory - [ NSBundle mainbundle ]

Tags: ios, objective-c

what is the difference between nshomedirectory and [nsbundle mainbundle]

how can i copy a file to the nshomedirectory / documents file from my mac ?

which one i need to choose for store .sqlite file ?

when and why i need to choose [nsbundle mainbundle] to some things ?

i found this site http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/where-to-store-files but it didn't told me the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSBundle mainBundle];
```

taken from apple site;

in general, the main bundle corresponds to an application file package or application wrapper: a directory that bears the name of the application and is marked by a “.app” extension.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
```

This method returns the appropriate path for modern application and framework bundles. This method may not return a path for non-standard bundle formats or for some older bundle formats.

```
NSHomeDirectory();
```

This outputs the users home directory for example /Users/someuser/

in iOS, the home directory is the application’s sandbox directory. In OS X, it is the application’s sandbox directory or **the current user’s home directory** (if the application is not in a sandbox)

**To answer your question:**
NSBundle mainbundle refers to the location of the *.app file in the filesystem where as NSHomeDirectory points to the users home directory and nothing to do with the location of your app.

I also added the [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]; option as this may be what your looking for.

have a look through NSBundle on the apple dev site for more info,
[NSBundle Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Sorry I cant help with your other query, ive got no experience using sqlite.

Comment: i solved that. if you want something to backed up by icloud. then open a home directory / document files and put in there.  if not, put in mainbundle.

Comment: @user_2738046 You should **never** put anything into the main bundle in your code.

Comment: @bbum ok but how can i add an existing .sqlite file to NSHomeDirectory() / document file ?